# How to use OAuth 2 to log out of Google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, logout

I'm using Google's OAuth 2 to log into a web application we're using in our office.

To log out, I send a revoke token request to Google, which works fine, after that I'm logged out of the application.

The problem is that this works only in office, where you're using your own computer.

The system breaks when you go to a customer and use their computer:

Logging in to the web application also logs you in to Google. Logging out of the web application only revokes the token for this application, it does not log you out of Google.

Which is an undesired behaviour if you're using someone else's computer.

So the question is: Is there any way to also log out of the Google account instead of just revoking the access token to the application, or do I have to tell everyone to remember they always have to log out twice?

Comment: For reference, the answer is to follow this link:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en